# Why is the domain inclusive of 0 and 1 in this problem?

Tags: derivatives

The problem in my textbook asks me to find the derivative of the following.

1. $y = \tan^{-1}\frac{3x - x^3}{1 - 3x^2}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt3} < x < \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$

I get here that the restraints are present for $x$ because if $x$ were equal to $\frac{-1}{\sqrt3}$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ then the denominator would be $0$ and $y$ will be undefined.

1. $y = \cos^{-1}\frac{1 - x^2}{1 + x^2}, 0 < x < 1$

Here, I don't understand why $0$ and $1$ aren't included. When $x = 1$, $y = \cos^{-1}(0)$ and when $x = 0$, $y = \cos^{-1}(1)$ both of which are defined right? So could someone please explain why the domain doesn't include $1$ and $0$ in the second question?

Comment: Does the textbook _ever_ ask for a derivative of a function defined on a closed (or half-closed) interval? It may have to do with the way the book defined the derivative.

Comment: No. All the questions have domains like this where the endpoints aren't included.

Comment: What book are you using? The clue is probable somewhere else in the textbook. Your second function is well define for all $x$.

Comment: It's the NCERT 12th grade math book. This is the standard book used across the nation.

Comment: If "derivative" is defined such that you need both a left and right derivative, you can only have a derivative at a number in the interior of the domain; if the number is the maximum of the domain then you can't have a right derivative there. It is possible to define a valid derivative anyway, but I would guess the author did not believe it was necessary to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Has someone pointed out un a comment to another answer, function does not have to be define on its largest possible domain.

In your examples, the domain is larger than what is define. First function
$$y=\tan^{-1}\frac{3x-x^3}{1-3x^2}$$
is define everywhere except for $x=\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}$, since the arctangente is define everywhere.

Second function is define everywhere since 
$$-1<\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\leq1$$
for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: So the retraints used in my book where completely arbitary and have no partiular reason for it behind it?

Comment: Probably, what book are you using?

Comment: The book is from the CBSE (central board of secondary education). It's like the national standard here in India. It's pdf format can be found online.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether there's any specific reason for the inequalities to be strict then in the case of the upper bound (1) i can't see one (but then why should there be?). As for the lower bound (0), $cos^{-1}$ isn't differentiable at 1, and so $y$ isn't differentiable at x=0.

Comment: You should also understand that a function does not HAVE TO be defined on its largest possible domain.  For example, I can, if I wish, define f(x) to be "$f(x)= x^2$ for 0< x< 1" only.

Comment: When x = 1, y = 0. $f'(x) = \frac{2}{1+x^2}$ and $f'(x)$ at x =1, is 1. So it is differentiable at x = 1 right?